# using ssh-keygen I can not enter a passphrase

Tags: ssh

When I run in my git bash the ssh-keygen I am asked to enter a filename to save there the key.

After I did type a name I got asked another question:

```
"Enter passphrase"
```

When I start typing now nothing is typed in the console or I do not see it...

Is that a bug or full purpose?

Comment: phasphrase is not visible when you type.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Echo is intentionally disabled for security reasons. You will not see even `*` symbols.

That mechanism is used very often in unix based systems. Like that no one will know even the length of your password.

You should just write the passphrase and press enter.

Comment: Further, `ssh-keygen` will require you to enter the pass phrase twice to make sure you entered what you intended to.

Answer (score 0):

It's intentional.  Many unix applications that ask for passwords don't echo the password back at you.